# AsyncCommand CanExecute handler

Tags: .net, wpf, asynchronous, icommand

I am using the @Stephen-Cleary [AsyncCommand implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) in WPF (.NET 4.0) and now I am trying to find out how to specify the CanExecute handler during command definition.

Usually I create the command like this:

```
            SaveCommandAsync = AsyncCommand.Create(async token =>
            {
                //async code    
            });
```

I don't see any Create overload so I can specify CanExecute logic.

Thank you,

Igor

Comment: Post a link to mentioned implementation.

Comment: This is a very popular async command implementation (link on the question) with many references over the web, but I could not find any sample or how to specify CanExecute behavior.

Comment: I think that the source from that article has educational purpose, it is there to show the approach, not to be used "as-is" in real-life apps. Instead I would suggest to look at [his library on github](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async). If you really want to keep that implementation, you can try to inherit AsyncCommand and override CanExecute.

Comment: I am using the GitHub thank you (but not the .net core version) since I am targeting .NET 4.0. The thing is that CanExecute logic depends on each command, so I would need a predicate, similar to a RelayCommand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Stephen Cleary's [Nito.Mvvm.Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async) project to achieve what you need.

Add nuget reference to the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-eta-05):
`<package id="Nito.Mvvm.Async" version="1.0.0-eta-05" targetFramework="net45" />`

**Create Xaml binding:**

`<Button Content="Toggle" Command="{Binding MyAsyncCommand}"></Button>`

**Create CustomAsyncCommand, specifying CanExecute function**

`MyAsyncCommand = new CustomAsyncCommand(AsyncAction, x=> !_isWorking);`

**Do some async work in AsyncAction**

```
private async Task AsyncAction(object obj) {
    _isWorking = true;
    MyAsyncCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    _isWorking = false;
    MyAsyncCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

And finally: [enjoy](http://screencast.com/t/MSuYuhSy1N4).

Comment: Unfortunately I am targeting .NET 4.0

Comment: The source you have pointed out is using `await` like in `AsyncCommandBase` there are usages like `await ExecuteAsync(parameter);`. `await` keyword is not available in .NET 4.0, how do you manage to compile that code then?

Comment: Good question. A few months ago I had to downgrade from .NET 4.5 to 4.0 so I was saved by the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package.

Comment: Well, I've just tried to combine all the source code from Stephen Cleary libraries and compile them under .net 4.0. Well, it's not that easy, there are some usages of `await` operator, `WeakReference<T>` and `Environment.ManagedThreadId`. But all of them can be ported to 4.0 quite easily. I haven't finished the test yet(have to run now), but does that sound like an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: Sure it does for me and maybe to someone else! Thank you!

Comment: Check [this](https://git.io/v1W2y) project, I've tested it locally and for base scenario it seems to work. I've just compiled Stephen Cleary's code under .NET 4.0... and it requires Microsoft.Bcl.Async to be installed in WPF project.

Comment: Thank you for that @3615. It seems this will work fine. I still need a couple of days to test it on my side and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sounds fair, hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm confused by this, it seems at some point that method's been changed to be protected:

https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/eea676b1f23881b4c755cc78dca4094928a59127/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/AsyncCommandBase.cs#L40

So I'm not really sure how it supports CanExecuteChanged at all?

Comment: @OwenP You are looking at base class, while the implementation [has `OnCanExecuteChanged` public](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/eea676b1f23881b4c755cc78dca4094928a59127/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/CustomAsyncCommand.cs#L116)

Answer (score 1):

Just for update this topic.

Currently actual reference implementation of AsyncCommand is in [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet) project that could be referenced with apropriate NuGet. And in code it could be written something like this:

```
// In properties declaration
public IAsyncRelayCommand MyCommand { get; }
// In ctor
MyCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(MyAction, () => MyCanExecute());
// Action declaration
private async Task MyAction() // Also could be a (CancellationToken token)
{ }
// Can exectute declaration
private bool DownloadTextCanExecute()
{ return !MyCommand.IsRunning; }
```

Make attention that CanExecute do not enables or disables a button that have a binding to apropriate Command. It just enables execution of a Command. In case if you want to represent a CanExecute by enabling or disabling a button, you could use something like the following in your XAML:

```
<Button
        Content="Click me!"
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding MyCommand.IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Implementation of a InverseBooleanConverter you could find in other answers. Or you could see a full code of a demo project [WpfAsyncCommandExample](https://github.com/bakulev/WpfAsyncCommandExample)